# ffmpeg concatenated file does not play as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying create a video by concatenating in this order:

[`video1.mp4`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/myh12/video1.mp4) **&**  [`video_from_static_image.mp4`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/myh12/video_from_static_image.mp4) **&** [`video1.mp4`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/myh12/video1.mp4)

`video1.mp4` is a simple video file. `video_from_static_image.mp4` was created from the [`a.png`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/myh12/a.png) image like this:

`ffmpeg  -y -framerate 25 -f image2  -loop 1 -i a.png -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 2 -r 25  video_from_static_image.mp4`

I create the final concatenated file through this command:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy final_concat.mp4`

I get the following message during the concat process:

`[mp4 @ 0x7fee6b815e00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 120678, current: 65722; changing to 120679. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`

The complete output when running the above command is [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/myh12/finalout.txt)

When I play [`final_concat.mp4`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/myh12/final_concat.mp4) it has problems with video_from_static_image.mp4 and it seems to skip it (and other variations resulted in playing for a short while). I've tried a bunch of things, but I believe they all point to the DTS error above.

BTW, all the video files are pretty small (< 1MB). Here are details about the version I am using:

`$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-vda
libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate `video_from_static_image.mp4` to have the same parameters as `video1.mp4` and also include silent filler audio:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 -loop 1 -i a.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 2 -shortest video_from_static_image.mp4
```

Now the frame rate, time base, H.264 profile, audio channels, audio rate, and stream order are the same.

Then run the concat command.